# Try-catch error message returns undefined on first time, but returns correct message the second time

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm having difficulties with displaying feedback messages on my Toasts in sveltekit.

This is the problem. When I log in with fake credentials, I receive a toast with undefined, and when I press the loginbutton again, I receive a correct error message. The same thing happens with the correct credentials. First time Undefined, second time correct credentials. I suspect it has something to do with async await but not sure about that.

+page.svelte:

```
<script>
        // @ts-ignore
    import Logo from "/src/components/Logo.svelte";
    import { enhance } from "$app/forms";
    import Toasts from "../../components/Toasts.svelte";
    import { addToast } from "../../stores";
    export let form;
  </script>

  <Toasts />

  <main>
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="image-container">
        <Logo width=200px/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" use:enhance>
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required />

        <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" required />

        <!-- <button on:click={console.log(form?.message)}>Login</button> -->
        <button on:click={() => addToast({ message: form?.message, type: form?.type })}>Login</button>
        <p>Nog geen account?<a href="/register">Registreer hier</a></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
```

+page.server.ts

```
import { auth } from "$lib/server/lucia";
import { LuciaError } from "lucia";
import { fail, redirect } from "@sveltejs/kit";
import type { Actions } from "./$types";

export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ request, locals }) => {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        const email = formData.get("email");
        const password = formData.get("password");
        // basic check
        if (
            typeof email !== "string" ||
            email.length < 4 ||
            !email.includes('@')
        ) {
            return fail(400, {
                message: "Uw gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord is verkeerd"
            });
        }
        if (
            typeof password !== "string" ||
            password.length < 4 ||
            password.length > 255
        ) {
            return fail(400, {
                message: "Uw gebruikersnaam en/of wachtwoord is verkeerd"
            });
        }
        try {
            // Perform login operations
            const key = await auth.useKey(
              "email",
              email.toLowerCase(),
              password
            );
            const session = await auth.createSession({
              userId: key.userId,
              attributes: {},
            });
            locals.auth.setSession(session); // set session cookie
          } catch (e) {
            if (
              e instanceof LuciaError &&
              (e.message === "AUTH_INVALID_KEY_ID" ||
                e.message === "AUTH_INVALID_PASSWORD")
            ) {
              // handle invalid credentials error
              return fail(400, {
                message: "Incorrect username or password",
                type: "error",
              });
            } else {
              // handle other errors
              return fail(500, {
                message: "An unknown error occurred",
                type: "error",
              });
            }
          }
        throw redirect(302, "/");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form` is only updated once the response from the server returns, the click happens before that, when the request is being sent.

You could [extend the `enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-customising-use-enhance) by providing a function that returns a response handle callback. There you can use `update` to first apply any default logic (see linked docs) and then additionally add the toast. Data from the action will be sent to the handler function as well, but if you want to read it from the `form` property you have await another [`tick()`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#tick) for that to update.

```
<!-- Using result: -->
<form method="post" use:enhance={() => async ({ update, result }) => {
    if (result.type == 'failure') {
        addToast({ message: result.data?.message });
    }
    else {
        await update();
    }
}}>

<!-- Using `form` -->
<form method="post" use:enhance={() => async ({ update }) => {
    await update();
    await tick();
    if (form)
      addToast({ message: form.message });
}}>
```

Note that this only works with JS, if it is disabled or fails to load (more likely scenario), the form will be posted with a full page reload. If you want something more robust, render the messages directly to the template, e.g.

```html
{#if form}
  <div class="message message-{form.type}">
    {form.message}
  </div>
{/if}
```

This can be server-side rendered on full reloads.

Comment: Can you give me a small example about that update function?

Comment: Did you read the linked docs? You just `await update()`.

Comment: I did read it, but still the same problem

Comment: The result handling function directly contains the result, so you *could* read the data directly from there, though it is wrapped. If you want to continue to get it from the `form` property, you would have to [wait another update cycle](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#tick), so you do `await update(); await tick();`, after that, `form` will contain the object returned from the action.

Comment: I'll give it a try!

Comment: I've wrote an anser with an update

Comment: Please delete that. It's *not* an answer, if anything, augment the question.

Comment: This does not make sense, you are again reading data from stuff that happens before the response comes back. As I wrote either get it from the result (which can have a `data` property) or await the `tick` and use the form property of the page (currently you are shadowing that with a deprecated submit event property that refers to the form element). You also should not have any logic on the button, that will always be too early. Added examples for both methods to my answer.

Comment: I give you my sincere apologies. I don't knnow why but I overlooked your answer, and that worked immediately.. .
I would like to thank you for your contribution and patience.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of H.B., I got to this but it's still returning undefined on the first submit..

```
<script lang="ts">
    // @ts-ignore
    import Logo from "/src/components/Logo.svelte";
    import { enhance, type SubmitFunction } from "$app/forms";
    import Toasts from "../../components/Toasts.svelte";
    import { addToast } from "../../stores";
    import type { ActionData, PageData } from "./$types.js";
    import { tick } from "svelte";

    export let data: PageData;
    export let form: ActionData;

    const submitCheck: SubmitFunction = ({ form, data }) => {
      const { title, content } = Object.fromEntries(data)

    return async ({ result, update }) => {
        switch (result.type) {
          case 'success':
              addToast({ message: 'tis oke', type: 'success' })
              break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        await update();
        await tick();
    }
  }
  </script>

  <Toasts />

  <main>
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="image-container">
        <Logo width=200px/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" use:enhance={submitCheck}>
        <h1>Login</h1>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required />

        <label for="password">Wachtwoord</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" required />

        <!-- <button on:click={console.log(form?.message)}>Login</button> -->
        <button on:click={() => addToast({ message: form?.message, type: form?.type })}>Login</button>
        <p>Nog geen account?<a href="/register">Registreer hier</a></p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
```